# Delete empty space between <h2> and CSS animation

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

In the following snippet you can see a space between `h2` and animation. I want it remove it in my case.How can I do this?

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>xyzxyzxyzxyz.
  <div class="loader" style="float:right;"></div>
</h2>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/wdzLv7tk/

Comment: is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/wdzLv7tk/4/

Comment: a span should be used since it stands inside h2 ;) https://jsfiddle.net/wdzLv7tk/11/ @marzelin

Comment: @G-Cyr well there're probably lots of ways in which this code can be improved further ;)

Comment: @marzelin it was just about valid HTML, valid HTML is a good practice and can avoid some funny behavior thinking css bugs when it is only about html. in this case it doesn't hurt much, but a good habit doesn't hurt either ;)

Comment: you're absolutely right, thanks for bringing it up @G-Cyr :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Float:right` cause the problem. There are so many ways to keep the element side by side. I applied one of them. Here I have `display:table` for my parent element and for each child it is `display:table-cell` which gives a solution to your problem.

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

.parent {
  display: table;
  margin:auto;
}

.child {
  display: table-cell;
}

h2 {}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h2 class="child">xyzxyzxyzxyz.</h2>
  <div class="loader child" style=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: so ,what if i want to center this div (parent)?
///ok i just use margin-left: x% ;p

Comment: To center the parent add `margin:auto` to `parent` which centers it in horizontal manner.I updated the answer. Do you want to center it vertically too?

Comment: `margin-left` is not a good manner to center a element. It cause problems in responsive. Check here for more alignment knowledge https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just use `text-align: right` instead of `text-align: center`

```css
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

/* Safari */
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
h2 {
text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h2>xyzxyzxyzxyz.<div class="loader" style="float:right;"></div></h2>
```